# Downgrading IIS version on windows server 2008

Tags: iis

Does anyone have an idea if it is possible to downgrade IIS version 7 to lower version of IIS on windows server 2008?
I have an ASP program on win 2000 server and I am planning to migrate this program on new setup on better hardware and software but I am getting HTTP 500 which in detail error logs I see complain of classic asp and IIS 7. In my case obviously the the ASP used (by another programmer) is and old classic ASP platform and now with this conflict I cannot get my web sever operating properly.

Any help/idea would be really appreciated.

Thanks,
Alan